# Transparencia en Ventanas PyQt No Funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Buenas tardes quiero generar un efecto de transparencia en mi ventana principal.
Pero al ejecutar el código no se ejecuta la transparencia y solo se pone un fondo negro:

Este es mi código:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(350,150,600,400)
        QMainWindow.setStyleSheet(self,'Background-color:rgba(255, 215, 255,20)') 

  #El valor de 20 es el filtro alfa para la transparencia pero no funciona


app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

## Resultado que quiero Obtener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**O bien un efecto aeroglass completamente "Solo si es posible"**

Comment: cual es tu OS??

Comment: Aunque no sea la solucion, deberias usar: `self.setStyleSheet('background-color:rgba(255, 215, 255,20)')` en vez de `QMainWindow.setStyleSheet(self,'Background-color:rgba(255, 215, 255,20)')`

Comment: windows 8 y windows 7

Comment: prueba con el siguiente codigo: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/fad53980dd3c33bc4cf40861f4cb45f3, si te funciono me indicas para publicar una respuesta sustentada.

Comment: No Funciono aun el fondo se ve negro

Comment: En linux funciona genial: https://imgur.com/a/iijFz, he visto errores similares en windows, te recomiendo revisar las posibles soluciones propuestas en el sitio en ingles.

Comment: encontre esto: (Qt.WA_PaintOnScreen), pero me arroja un error:

Comment: Este es el error: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import Qt

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Principal, self).__init__()

        lbl = Qt.QLabel('Transparencia en Ventanas PyQt Funciona !!', self)
        lbl.setStyleSheet("""QLabel{
          font-family:'Consolas'; 
          color: red; 
          font-size: 26px;}""")
        lbl.setGeometry(7, 20, 586, 30)


        self.setAttribute(Qt.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True )   
        self.setAttribute(Qt.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)      
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.setStyleSheet("Principal{background-color: rgba(0, 215, 55, 70);}") 


  #El valor de 20 es el filtro alfa para la transparencia pero no funciona

        self.boton1 = Qt.QPushButton("Quit", self)
        self.boton1.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.boton1.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.988818, y1:0.915, x2:0, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(53, 129, 90, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"font: 75 16pt \"Georgia\";")
        self.boton1.setGeometry(225, 170, 150, 150)
        self.boton1.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.setGeometry(350,150,600,400)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nick I saw that all your answers are without explanation and in english. Remember this site is in spanish so if you publish something, do it in spanish language. You need to provide more info in your answers to be valid here. Regards